# Getting UTF-8 character issue in Oracle and Java

Tags: java, oracle

Have one table in Oracle which contains column type is `NVARCHAR2`. In this column I am trying to save Russian characters. But it showing ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿ like this. When I try to fetch same characters from Java, I am getting same string.

I have try with `NCHAR` `VARCHAR2`. But in all cases same issue.

Is this problem from Java or Oracle? I have try same Java code, same characters using PostgreSQL which is working fine. I am not getting whether this problem is from Oracle or Java?

In my oracle database `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` property value is `AL16UTF16`.
Any Idea how can I show UTF-8 characters as it is in Java which saved in Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some google I have resolved my issue. Here is ans: `AL32UTF8 is the Oracle Database character set that is appropriate for XMLType data. It is equivalent to the IANA registered standard UTF-8 encoding, which supports all valid XML characters.`

It means while creating database in Oracle, set `AL32UTF8` character set.

Here is link for this

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/create.htm#i1008322

Answer (score 1):

Problem with characters is that you cannot trust your eyes. Maybe the database stores the correct character values but your viewing tool does not understand them. Or maybe the characters get converted somewhere along the way due to language settings.

To find out what character values are stored in your table use the `dump` function:

Example:

```
select dump(mycolumn),mycolumn from mytable;
```

This will give you the byte values of your data and you can check whether or not the values in your table are as they should be.

Comment: I have execute your query which gives result `Typ=1 Len=28: 0,191,0,191,0,191,0,191,0,191,0,191,0,191,0,191,0,191,0,191,0,191,0,191,0,191,0,191` which means it stores `¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿` characters only.

Comment: Also to view data from postgreSQL and Oracle I am using same client which is Squirrel. So same characters are showing properly from ProstgreSQL and not from Oracle

Comment: So is the issue with inserting the correct values into the Oracle table? To test what happens if you store the correct values you can insert using the unistr function. 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions204.htm

Comment: Thank for your reply. I insert some char using `UNISTR` which works fine. my +1 for this. Now the problem is do I need to convert each characters in `Unicode code point` and then insert it in table? to insert on char in table I used `insert into test values(UNISTR('\0426'))` which works fine. Please suggest me.....

Comment: Is there any way to save Russian characters in Oracle table? Is Oracle supports all UTF-8 char? Else I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8`  while getting the connection from the database. Also make sure the column supports `UTF-8` encoding. Go through [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch6unicode.htm).